# Find a string in one section of a file with mutiple sections

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, scripting

How to sed/awk for a string contained in another string.

```
TESTVAR='
{
 icon : "icons/773_l.png",
 id : 80,
 initialState : true,
 isPng : false,
 label : "Imagery",
 opacity : 1,
 requestType : "UUID",
 version : 79
}
,
{
 icon : "thisicon",
 id : 8080,
 initialState : false,
 isPng : true,
 label : "Boundaries",
 opacity : 1,
 requestType : "NothingSpecial",
 version : 8
}
```

I need select the `version : 79` for the object that contains `requestType : "UUID"`. 
How would I select everything inside the first block, then select the version, and just have a command return `79`.
I have been trying for some time but don't know how to only select everything between the first `{}`. Once I have that I would then just need to get the number after `version :`.

I thought this would work but it hasn't `awk '/\{/{f=1;next}/\}/{f=0}f' test.txt`

In addition, order is not guaranteed. So I really need to select everything inside `{` and `}` containing "UUID". Then select `version : \([0-9]+\)`

This is close but too greedy: `sed -e 's/{\(.*UUID.*\)}/\1/' test.txt`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045927/unix-regex-with-sed-search-across-multiple-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First what comes to my mind is neither sed nor awk:

```
$ tr -d '\n' < file | grep -Po 'requestType : "UUID"\K.*? version : \K[0-9]*'
79
```

Probably can be done easier, especially if you can guarantee that "version" comes right after "requestType".

In case if `version` doesn't have to go after `requested Type` things are little bit more complicated:

```
$ tr -d '\n' < file | grep -Po '{.[^}]*?requestType : "UUID".*?}' | grep -Po 'version : \K[0-9]*'
79
```

If there are more sections which can match all of them will be printed:

```
$ cat file
TESTVAR='
{
 icon : "icons/773_l.png",
 id : 80,
 initialState : true,
 isPng : false,
 label : "Imagery",
 opacity : 1,
 version : 79,
 requestType : "UUID"
}
,
{
 icon : "thisicon",
 id : 8080,
 initialState : false,
 isPng : true,
 label : "Boundaries",
 opacity : 1,
 requestType : "NothingSpecial",
 version : 8
}
,
{
 icon : "icons/773_l.png",
 id : 80,
 initialState : true,
 isPng : false,
 label : "Imagery",
 opacity : 1,
 requestType : "UUID",
 version : 87
}
,
{
 icon : "icons/773_l.png",
 id : 80,
 version : 17,
 initialState : true,
 isPng : false,
 label : "Imagery",
 opacity : 1,
 requestType : "UUID"
}
,
{
 icon : "thisicon",
 id : 8080,
 requestType : "NothingSpecial",
 initialState : false,
 label : "Boundaries",
 opacity : 1,
 version : 18,
 isPng : true
}

$ tr -d '\n' < file | grep -Po '{.[^}]*?requestType : "UUID".*?}' | grep -Po 'version : \K[0-9]*'
79
87
17
```

Comment: Close. This works great for the example. Can't guarantee the "version" will come right after "requestType". I actually can't guarantee that it will always come AFTER. So if version comes first that will not work.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: This is the one that works best for my case. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this purely with `sed`:

```
$ sed -rn '/\{/{:a;N;/\}/{/requestType : "UUID"/s/.*version : ([0-9]+).*/\1/p;d};ba}' <<< "$TESTVAR"
79
$
```

This is adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18046021/2113226 for your data.

---

You mention that this is a javascript data structure, so I think the most reliable method to parse it would be using javascript.  I installed Node.js to do this, but I assume any command-line javascript interpreter should be able to do something like this:

```
$ echo "arr=[$TESTVAR]; console.log(arr.filter(function(elem) { return elem.requestType === \"UUID\"; })[0].version)" | node
79
$
```

#### Disclaimer

You'd have to be sure of the data here.  I don't know javascript that well, but I think code-injection would be quite possible if the input data string was crafted just right.

Answer (score 1):

awk lets you define the record separator, so instead of a newline (each line is a record), use "}\n" as the end of the record:

```
echo "$TESTVAR" |
gawk -v RS="}\n" '
    /requestType : "UUID"/ && match($0, /version : ([0-9]+)/, m) {print m[1]}
'
```

```
79
```

This is GNU awk specific, for the match() function.

---

Too bad this isn't valid JSON. Then you could use a JSON parser:

```
jq '(.[] | select(.requestType == "UUID")).version' <<JSON
[
 {
  "icon" : "icons/773_l.png",
  "id" : 80,
  "initialState" : true,
  "isPng" : false,
  "label" : "Imagery",
  "opacity" : 1,
  "requestType" : "UUID",
  "version" : 79
 }
 ,
 {
  "icon" : "thisicon",
  "id" : 8080,
  "initialState" : false,
  "isPng" : true,
  "label" : "Boundaries",
  "opacity" : 1,
  "requestType" : "NothingSpecial",
  "version" : 8
 }
]
JSON
```

Comment: I wish it was just JSON. It's a wget response with some javascript inside. Also will not have access to any libraries like jq.

Comment: @kosmos See my edited answer for parsing this directly with a javascript interpreter